# How to increase the topic consumer throughput by using `Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>`?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, reactor, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a service based on webFlux and will consume then produce message from a kafka topic.
My code is just like this

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> reactiveUpperCase() {
    return flux -> flux.map(val -> val.toUpperCase());
}
```

What I found is when I have 2 instance, I could consume 750 message per 30 minutes, but my CPU is never higher than 10%.
As time goes by, the lag keeps increasing, so I'm wondering how could I increase the consumer throughput.
From the documents, the concurrency doesn't take effect for reactive, [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/5867636d17123876da3263691fb064af67f7694b)

Does any one know how could I increase the throughput without adding more instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm using kotlin, what I found is using `Flow.flatMapMerge(parallelCount)`